# Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (13)

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to insert data with spring-data-cassandra. But I am getting bellow error , when my app is running with SpringBoot(version is 1.5.3)

I add a custom CallHistoriyRespority object implemented CrudResposity in spring-data, and use the save method to insert the data object

I can't find any reason and the problem confused me

Full stack trace :

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (13)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:177)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2500(RequestHandler.java:46)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:799)
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:633)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1070)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:993)
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:295)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:269)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

cassandra table description is below :

```
CREATE TABLE userdevices.callhistorylogs (
userid bigint,
deviceid text,
serialnumber timestamp,
objectid text,
dialtime timestamp,
dialtype int,
duration int,
phone text,
simid int,
targetphone text,
PRIMARY KEY ((userid, deviceid), serialnumber, objectid)
```

and my java configuration is below :

```
@Table("callhistorylogs")
public class CallHistoryLogPO{
 @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0 ,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
 private Long userID;

 @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
 private String deviceID;

 @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 2,type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
 private String serialNumber;

 @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 3,type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
 private String objectID;

 private Date dialTime;

 private Call.DialType dialType;

 private Integer duration;

 private String phone;

 private Integer simID;

 private String targetPhone;
 .....
}
```

save method is below :

```
    CallHistoriesPO callHistories = new CallHistoriesPO();
    callHistories.setUserID(20170627L);
    callHistories.setDeviceID("160129999");
    callHistories.setPhone("17681879236");
    ......
    callHistoryResposity.save(callHistories);
```

Comment: `serialNumber` is timestamp which maps to `java.util.Date`.... while you are using `String`

Comment: you are right, I have solved this problem, thanks.

Comment: if you want you can delete this question... else i can post my comment as answer... so that question will not be unanswered... Thanks

Comment: @undefined_variable I'd say go ahead and post your comment as an answer.  I'll even up-vote you :D

Comment: @Aaron Done... Thanks... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`serialNumber` is timestamp in cassandra which maps to `java.util.Date`, while you are using `String` for `serialNumber`.

[cql-to-java-type-mapping](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping)

Comment: Note that `timestamp` will also map to `java.time.Instant`