# Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (25)

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

I developing application using Cassandra and SpringBoot.
I have written Cassandra query in Java;

```
String userName="testUser";
String lastUpdatedDate="2018-11-29 13:00:43.400";
String tenantName="demo";

Select select = QueryBuilder.select().all()
                    .from(tenantName,getGenericClass().getSimpleName())
                    .where(QueryBuilder.eq("user_Name", userName))
                    .and(QueryBuilder.gt("last_updateddate",  lastUpdatedDate))
                    .allowFiltering()
                    .limit(100);
           return (List<T>) cassandraOperations.select(select, getGenericClass());
```

last_updateddate is timestamp data type column in Cassandra.  userName and last_updateddate columns are composite key in database and using latest version of Cassandra.

while executing getting the following error.

Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (25)

but

Issue got resolved after below change.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date date = sdf.parse(lastUpdatedDate);
long timeInSec = date.getTime();

Timestamp ts=new Timestamp(timeInSec);  
Date date1=ts;                                                                                                         
 Select select = QueryBuilder.select().all()
                        .from(tenantName,getGenericClass().getSimpleName())
                        .where(QueryBuilder.eq("user_Name", userName))
                        .and(QueryBuilder.gt("last_updateddate",  date1))
                        .allowFiltering()
                        .limit(100);
               return (List<T>) cassandraOperations.select(select, getGenericClass());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772444/caused-by-com-datastax-driver-core-exceptions-invalidqueryexception-expected-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772444/caused-by-com-datastax-driver-core-exceptions-invalidqueryexception-expected-8)

Comment: Alex/Ankur: This issue is having during select query but old issue was raised for the insert operation.

Comment: Issue resolved after changing the date formate( from String to Date Formate.) and updated above change made in the code . so that any one have same issue may helpfull

Answer (score 0):

you have to check data type of Cassandra table and use corresponding datatype of java and use it in java code when declaring variable to pass value of column .

Example : In Cassandra LocalDate then define LocalDate of cassandra.core package in java instead Date or LocalDate of util package.

check this [type mapping between Cassandra vs Java](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping)